# How to record UI test in xcode when there is no storyboard file?

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xcode-ui-testing

I'm new to mac,xamarin and xcode. As a tester I want to automate UI test in xcode. How do I open xamarin project in xcode and record UI test? Please note that in our project we are not using storyboard for UI. 
Can someone explain the steps to follow?

regards,
Flash

Comment: I would suggest writing your tests with UITest: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/

Comment: You can't open Xamarin iOS projects in XCode. And whether or not you use a storyboard should not matter for UI Tests. Also I mirror BytesGuys suggestion to use Xamarin.UITest to automate UI Testing for Xamarin Projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the steps for you:

1. Learn more about Mac here: https://support.apple.com/explore/new-to-mac
2. Install Xamarin and Xcode: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/mac/
3. Setup project for UITest: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/
4. How to use xamarin test recorder to record UITest: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/testrecorder/

Other useful tutorials/video on Xamarin test recorder:

https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-a-ui-test-suite-with-the-xamarin-test-recorder/
https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Snack-Pack-3-Xamarin-Test-Recorder-for-macOS